# Comparing strings in 2 list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I need to compare to list with strings, and find whitch elements that are similar. ie.

```
List<string> listA = {"ProfileHeight", "ProfileWidth", "WebThickness"}
List<string> listB ={"ProfileHeightVisibility", "ProfileWidthVisibility", "WebThicknessVisibility", "FlangeThicknessVisibility", "DepthVisibility"}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use Linq. I want the result to be a list with the elements from ListB that have a name similar to the strings in listA. Where the statemant i.e. "ProfileHeightVisibility.Contains("ProfileHeight") = true

Comment: And by "similar" you mean `StartsWith` or `Contains`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mean you want items in listB `where` it contains `any` of the elements in listA?

```
listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => b.Contains(a))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in LINQ:

```
listB.Where(e => listA.Any(a => e.Contains(a)));
```

Bear in mind that this algorithm has a runtime cost similar to *O(n^2)*, it will therefore slow down quickly as the number of elements in your lists grows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement things like that :

```
  public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
  {

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
      return y.Contains(x);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
      return 1;
    }
   }
```

and then use intersect like that:

```
 listB.Intersect(listA, new EqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do such thing with LINQ

```
    public List<string> GetSimilarStrings(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
    {
        return (from item in list1 from item2 in list2 where string.Equals(item,item2,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) select item).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `string.Compare`? This method returns an integer stating the lexical order of two strings rather than a boolean, does it not?

Comment: Yeah, good point. I corrected my answer. Comparing strings by "==" could cause problems with culture, encoding or case sensitiveness of words. This example shows how to handle those things.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the strings are supposed to be *equal*. However, I'd maybe rather use `string.Equals(a, b, StringComparision.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx

Comment: You are right, it could be even better to use    String.Equals.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "zinmin", "zin1", "zin2" };
List<string> listB = new List<string> { "zinmin", "min1", "min2" };



List<string> matching = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList();
```

matching result will come {"zinmin"} . Sorting order doesn't matter.